# Problema con un webview

Tags: android-studio, webview-android

Tengo un problema con un `WebView`, el diseño de mi aplicación usa **Tabs** y `Navigation Drawer`, en las Tabs tengo fragmentos que muestran contenido mediante un `webview`, el problema es que cada que cambio de **Tabs** los `webview` se vuelven a actualizar, hay alguna manera de evitarlo?

En la imagen se supone que ya estaba cargado mi contenido de la Tab "Convenios"
pero al regresar a esa Tab vuelve a cargar como si fuera la primera vez que se abre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del adaptador:

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context) {
        super(manager);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return new BlogFragment();
            case 1: return new ConveniosFragment();
            case 2: return new FavoritosFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return context.getString(R.string.blog);
            case 1: return context.getString(R.string.convenios);
            case 2: return context.getString(R.string.favoritos);
        }
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }
}
```

---

Este es el código de `ConveniosFragment();`

```
public class ConveniosFragment extends Fragment {
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.conveniosfragment, container, false);

        View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.conveniosfragment, container, false);
        WebView webView = (WebView)mainView.findViewById(R.id.viewConvenios);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize (1024 * 1024 * 8 );
        webView.canGoBack();
        webView.goBack();
        webView.loadUrl("http://seccion15.org.mx/convenios/");

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Espere...",
                "Cargando contenido.", true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progress != null)
                    progress.dismiss();
            }
        });
        return mainView;


    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

    }

}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de la actividad donde implementas el `PageAdapter`.

Comment: Es este el Adaptador que uso:

Comment: Donde esta el adaptador que no lo veo?

Comment: public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context) {
        super(manager);
        this.context = context;
    }

    
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return new BlogFragment();
            case 1: return new ConveniosFragment();
            case 2: return new FavoritosFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

Comment: @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return context.getString(R.string.blog);
            case 1: return context.getString(R.string.convenios);
            case 2: return context.getString(R.string.favoritos);
        }
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }

Comment: Agrega el código en tu pregunta, no en los comentarios, para así se pueda entender mejor

Comment: ConveniosFragment(); como cargas tu Webview? con un Async ? por que si es así siempre se ejecutara cuando vayas a este fragment

Comment: @AshleyG. agrego el código a la pregunta pero no es con un Async

Comment: tu webiview siempre se ejecutara donde esta la carga en el onCreate, es decir cada vez que entres, lo que haria yo es que cuando el usuario entre por primera vez al fragment le mostaria un mensaje con lo que contiene el fragmento (una reseña) y un botón Mostrar o cargar contenido. y luego muestras el contenido, y cada vez que quiera refrescar sera por medio onRefresh() que es deslizar el dedo hacia abajo. Es una opción

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia Ashley, ya implemente un onRefresh en mis fragment y voy a seguir tu consejo.

Comment: espero  se arregle tu problema, así evitas que se actualice constantemente tu fragment , saludos.

Comment: @Kikehatake si agregas el código completo de la actividad donde tienes el `PagerAdapter`, te puedo dar una respuestas mas especifica a tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas creando un nuevo fragmento cada vez que cambias de pagina. Para solucionar tu problema crea un `ArrayList` de tipo `Fragment` que contenga todos los fragmentos que utilizas en el `ViewPager`. Después en el método `getItem()` obtienes los fragmentos del `ArrayList`, utilizando el parámetro `position`, y los retornas.

> En el código que agregaste, no pusiste la actividad que contiene el ViewPager, por lo que me haré a la idea de que es la actividad `MainActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        // Creas los fragmentos
        BlogFragment blogFragment  = new BlogFragment();
        ConveniosFragment conveniosFragment =  new ConveniosFragment();
        FavoritosFragment favoritosFragment = new FavoritosFragment();

        // Creas el ArrayList que contendrá los diferentes fragmentos
        ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentos = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragmentos.add(blogFragment);
        fragmentos.add(conveniosFragment);
        fragmentos.add(favoritosFragment);

        ...

        // Pasas el ArrayList fragmentos como parámetro al constructor
        // del PageAdapter.
        TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentos);
        ...

    }

    ...

    public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentos;

        // Recibe la lista de fragmentos que se mostraran el ViewPager.
        public TabAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context, ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentos) {
            super(manager);
            this.context = context;

            // Le asignas el ArrayList fragmentos a la variable fragmentos.
            this.fragmentos = fragmentos;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            // Obtienes el fragmento que se encuentra en la posición
            // de la pagina del ViewPager y lo retornas.
            return fragmentos.get(position);
        }

        ...

    }
}
```

> Los tres puntos **...** significan: existencia de mas lineas de código.

He modificado un poco la implementación de tu código, pero te aseguro, de esta manera esta mejor implementado. Ahora podrás tener un mayor control sobre los diferentes fragmentos, control que antes no lo tenias.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad es un comportamiento esperado, ya que cada vez que cambies de tab cargas un `Fragment`, en este caso cuando se carga el `Fragment` que contiene el `WebView` vuelve a cargar.

Para evitar la recarga puedes usar [setRetainInstance(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)):

> [setRetainInstance(boolean retain)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) Controla si una instancia de fragmento se
>   retiene en la recreación de la actividad (por ejemplo, desde un cambio
>   de configuración).

Agrega  `setRetainInstance(true);` dentro de `onCreate()` de tu `Fragment`:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Lo intente como mencionas en tu respuesta pero no hace nada esa linea de código, el problema persiste.

Comment: Agregaste en el Fragment setRetainInstance(true); ?

Comment: si así es, de echo también intente almacenar el contenido del webview en el cache pero aun así sigue fallando

Answer (score 0):

Complementando la respuesta de David Minaya, también debes agregar

```
Viewpager2.offscreenpagelimit = n - 1
```

Para que mantenga la cantidad de fragmentos de tu lista, se le quita uno porque siempre habrá uno visible y los demás no.